# How to parse Advanced Json Data

Tags: javascript, json, api, getjson

I have a JSON output like below. I am using getjson to get data. My aim is to take `datetime` and `value` field(italic and bold) like `[16:35:08,30.579 kbit/s],[16:35:38,23.345 kbit/s]`. Is there any way to succeed this? Thanks,

```
{
    "prtg-version": "17.3.33.2830",
    "treesize": 4,
    "histdata": [{
        "***datetime***": "04.12.2017 16:35:08",
        "datetime_raw": 43073.5660648727,
        "value": "111.983 KByte",
        "value_raw": 114670936.0000,
        "***value***": "30.579 kbit/s",
        "value_raw": 3822364.5333,
        "value": "107.893 KByte",
        "value_raw": 110482503.0000,
        "value": "29.462 kbit/s",
        "value_raw": 3682750.1000,
        "value": "4.090 KByte",
        "value_raw": 4188433.0000,
        "value": "1.117 kbit/s",
        "value_raw": 139614.4333,
        "coverage": "100 %",
        "coverage_raw": 10000
    }, {
        "***datetime***": "04.12.2017 16:35:38",
        "datetime_raw": 43073.5664120718,
        "value": "85.464 KByte",
        "value_raw": 87514907.0000,
        "***value***": "23.345 kbit/s",
        "value_raw": 2918136.2788,
        "value": "81.993 KByte",
        "value_raw": 83960378.0000,
        "value": "22.397 kbit/s",
        "value_raw": 2799612.4708,
        "value": "3.471 KByte",
        "value_raw": 3554529.0000,
        "value": "948 kbit/s",
        "value_raw": 118523.8079,
        "coverage": "100 %",
        "coverage_raw": 10000
    }]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried yet? what should the output look like?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But you should at least try to do some research, try to implement it and then come back with a question if you get stuck.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). **Research, try something, add your code & point your problem.**

Comment: Most browsers will parse your JSON into an object with only one "value" field. Since you have repeated "value" keys in your JSON, each time the parser finds a the "value" key, it writes the new value of that key into the same "value" field. So for the first `histdata`, the value of "value" ends up being "1.117 kbit/s".

Comment: What exactly is the question here? There is nothing particularly "advanced" about your json. It's just json. What are you missing?

Answer (score 0):

Simply by map you array into a function and then parse the values as you desire.

The following example uses:

- [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to loop through the array
- [String.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to split the string using whitespace and get only the last part
- [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) ``` `` ``` to output the value

Relevant method:

```
const result = data.histdata.map(hist => {
  const datetime = hist['***datetime***'].split(' ')[1];
  const value = hist['***value***'];
  return `${datetime},${value}`;
});
```

Check the snippet:

```js
const data = {
    "prtg-version": "17.3.33.2830",
    "treesize": 4,
    "histdata": [{
        "***datetime***": "04.12.2017 16:35:08",
        "datetime_raw": 43073.5660648727,
        "value": "111.983 KByte",
        "value_raw": 114670936.0000,
        "***value***": "30.579 kbit/s",
        "value_raw": 3822364.5333,
        "value": "107.893 KByte",
        "value_raw": 110482503.0000,
        "value": "29.462 kbit/s",
        "value_raw": 3682750.1000,
        "value": "4.090 KByte",
        "value_raw": 4188433.0000,
        "value": "1.117 kbit/s",
        "value_raw": 139614.4333,
        "coverage": "100 %",
        "coverage_raw": 10000
    }, {
        "***datetime***": "04.12.2017 16:35:38",
        "datetime_raw": 43073.5664120718,
        "value": "85.464 KByte",
        "value_raw": 87514907.0000,
        "***value***": "23.345 kbit/s",
        "value_raw": 2918136.2788,
        "value": "81.993 KByte",
        "value_raw": 83960378.0000,
        "value": "22.397 kbit/s",
        "value_raw": 2799612.4708,
        "value": "3.471 KByte",
        "value_raw": 3554529.0000,
        "value": "948 kbit/s",
        "value_raw": 118523.8079,
        "coverage": "100 %",
        "coverage_raw": 10000
    }]
}

const result = data.histdata.map(hist => {
  const datetime = hist['***datetime***'].split(' ')[1];
  const value = hist['***value***'];
  return `${datetime},${value}`;
});

console.log(result)
```